# Convertir Json a query string con =

Tags: javascript, sql, nodejs, json, regex

Tengo este json `{"first":"Juan", "query": "sanidad", "limit":2}` me gustaria saber como convertirlo a

`first = Juan`
`query = sanidad`
`limit = 2`

alguien puede ayudarme, necesito la solución en javascript.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Recuerda que tu pregunta no debe parecer un [ticket para desarrollo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433). Lee [ask].

Comment: He intentado hacer un for of y en cada elemento añadir un = pero busco un metodo más rapido

Comment: Queres crear un array o convertirlo en otra cadena pero siguiendo el criterio que especificas?

Answer (score 1):

parseas el JSON para obtener el objeto y despues despues operar con un for...in sobre el. Espero te sirva. Saludos.

```
var jsonTexto = '{"first":"Juan", "query": "sanidad", "limit":2}';
var object = JSON.parse(jsonTexto);

for (const property in object) {
    console.log(`${property}: ${object[property]}`);
}
```